# Picking the smallest value in a list using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

This is a function I defined in order to find the smallest value in a list using recursion.However,I called the function twice within itself, which I think it's a bit weird. 
Is there a way around the function `append()`?. We haven't studied it yet so I'm asking whether there could be a simpler way to get the same solution by not using `append()`?

```
def minimum(lst):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list
    return : the value of the smallest element in the lst
    """
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]

    if lst[0] < lst[1]:
        lst.append(lst[0])
        return(minimum(lst[1:]))
    return(minimum(lst[1:]))
```

Comment: It is not proper at all for a function like `minimum` to alter its argument...

Comment: Just do the `append` and don't do the `return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could do this to avoid append:

```
def minimum(lst):

    if len(lst)==1:
        return lst[0]

    if lst[0] < lst[1]:
        return minimum(lst[0:1]+ lst[2:])
    else:
        return minimum(lst[1:])
```

but i think this one is better with only one call to minimum:

```
def minimum(lst):        
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]        
    s = minimum(lst[1:])

    return s if s < lst[0] else lst[0]
```

Comment: `return minimum(lst[0:1]+ lst[2:])` isn't `lst[0:1]` and `lst[0]` one and the same ?

Comment: one is a list of one integer ex: [1], the other an integer  ex: 1

Comment: important here as [1] + 2 is not allowed, while [1] + [2] gives [1,2]

Answer (score 2):

Use an additional variable?

```
def minimum(lst, current_min=None):
    if not lst:
        return current_min
    if current_min is None:
        current_min = lst[0]
    elif lst[0] < current_min:
        current_min = lst[0]
    return minimum(lst[1:], current_min)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very explicit version that should be easy to read due to comments and variable names.

```
def minimum(lst):
    # base case
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]

    # get first element and minimum of remaining list
    first = lst[0]
    rest = lst[1:]
    min_of_rest = minimum(rest)

    # return the smaller one of those two values
    if first < min_of_rest:
        return first
    else:
        return min_of_rest
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, I'd be tempted to try:

```
def minimum(lst):
    if not lst:
        return None

    a, *rest = lst

    if rest:
        b = minimum(rest)

        if b < a:
            return b

    return a
```

Most of the proposed solutions, with the exception of @roeen30 (+1) but including the currently accepted one, don't defend themselves against `minimum([])`.   Many go into an infinite recursion as a result!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following program:

```
def minimum(lst):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list
    return : the value of the smallest element in the lst
    """
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    temp_min = minimum(lst[1:])
    if lst[0] < temp_min:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        return temp_min
```

Comment: I struggled if it was ok to use "min" or not :-) return min(lst) is awfully tempting then :-) (not me that downvoted)

Comment: @ChristianSloper You are right sir. I missed that, I should have used if condition. And yes, Sorry I did not see that you have answered correct while I was writing my answer. :-(

Answer (score -1):

If your task is simply to find the smallest value in a list with any given length, I don't exactly know why you are using recursion. There are more efficient ways to do this such as built-in functions of Python. For example:

```
list_of_ints = [4,2,7,6,8,1,5,9,2]
print(min(list_of_ints)
```

This will print out 1.

Comment: the min function is better than sorting?   so if you want to use built in functions go with min(list)

Comment: sorting is O(n log n)  , min function is O(n)